# Distance calculation using Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Is there any way to get distance as a virtual attribute in a rails query?

currently i am using this :

```
users = User.find_by_sql("select u.*,((6371 * 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(((latitude - #{location.latitude}) * PI() / 180)/2),2) + cos(#{location.latitude} * PI() / 180) * cos(latitude * PI() / 180) * pow(sin(((longitude - #{location.longitude})* PI() / 180)/2),2))))* 0.62137) AS distance from users u
```

This provides me desired result, but i want to know is there any possibility to perform it using Geocoder or any other gem. Please help...

Thanks

Comment: check https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries

Comment: I want to use this result as JSON object so i need distance attribute as a part of objects returned by the sql query.